# C++ Characters/Symbols

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    cout << "ÍÍÍÍÍ";
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

What is this symbols called, and how can I find other characters like this "Í" to print symbols? It is it ASCII value?

Comment: You mind find [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) about character sets helpful. This question is not about C++, but rather about mismatching character encodings between your source file and terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol in your output is character number 205 from [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), one of the [box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character). It is one of the characters that had been used to draw text-based "windows" under DOS. I am not aware of a name for this specific character, other than something descriptive like "horizontal double-line".

The symbol in your source code is [character 205 in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8D). Apparently, when a character whose numeric value is `205` appears in your source code, your editor shows the Unicode character, but when it appears as your output, your terminal shows the code page 437 character.

If you can enter the `Í` character in your source code by holding down `Alt` and pressing 205 on your numeric keypad, then you can probably get the other characters from code page 437 similarly (replace 205 with the three-digit code for the character you want). The box drawing characters range from 179 to 218.

If you deal with Unicode characters directly, see the [Latin-1 Supplement block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)#Character_table) for a list of the characters in the extended ASCII range (128 through 255). This list has the codes in hexadecimal; the box drawing characters range from `0xB3` (superscript 3) to `0xDA` (acute capital U).